# Android login using firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

For my project, I do not have any kind of registration. I have inserted data in the cloud firestore. I have used this code but I couldn't succeed.

```
public class admin_login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admin");
    EditText admid, pssword;
    FirebaseFirestore fstore;
    Button adminsignin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_login);

        admid = findViewById(R.id.admin_id);
        pssword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        adminsignin = findViewById(R.id.admin_login_btn);


        fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        adminsignin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.admin_login_btn:
                if(admid.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "Please enter valid email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if( pssword.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "Please enter valid password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                fstore.collection("admin")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                                        String a=doc.getString("username");
                                        String b=doc.getString("password");
                                        String a1=admid.getText().toString();
                                        String b1=pssword.getText().toString();
                                        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(a1) & b.equalsIgnoreCase(b1)) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(admin_login.this, admin_home_page.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
                                        }else
                                            Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "Cannot login,incorrect Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(task.isSuccessful()){` and if the task is not successful ?

Answer (score 0):

If a task is not successful, it contains an exception with the cause of the failure.

You should get and log that exception to find the cause of the problem:

```
fstore.collection("admin")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    ...
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("Firestore", "Error getting data", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

This is almost exactly as the code sample in the Firebase documentation on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java_2), so I recommend keeping that handy as you code.

Comment: W/Firestore: (24.1.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
    
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: i got this error

Comment: E/Firestore: Error getting data
    com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Both of these are errors that have been covered before, so I recommend searching for them separately. Going forward: use the approach I showed here to find the root cause of any failed tasks in your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String email=edt_em_1.getText().toString();
            String pass=edt_pass_1.getText().toString();
            db1.collection("UserSignUp").whereEqualTo("Email",email).whereEqualTo("Password",pass)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
                        int i=0,j=0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            if(document.exists()){
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "success    "+document.get("Email"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong details ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```